# Faking class without interface

Tags: java, unit-testing

I prefer using fake classes over mocks (more readable) when unit testing. This worked well for me in Python but in the Java world I would normally need to create an interface for the class I'm replacing. That means that instead of 1 class, I now have 3:

- original class
- an interface
- a fake version for testing

If I want to achieve a really good test coverage, this effectively means I need to do this for every single class in my project which is unacceptable. I only want to create an interface for classes that really are going to have more than one implementation in the production code.

I noticed that Mockito lets you mock concrete classes without creating an interface. Can I use some trick like that for fake classes?

For example when testing a registration system, there would be an emailing class. Now in test I don't actually want to send out actual emails so I either mock or fake this class.

```
class FakeEmailService {   
  public void sendEmail(String to, String body) {
    m_sent = true;
  }
}
```

Now my registration system constructor accepts the original class, `EmailService` but I would like, with some trick, to use the `FakeEmailService` in the test:

`Registration reg = new Registration(new FakeEmailService());`

This is fine in Python since it's not statically typed.

Comment: Explain what a "fake" class is.

Comment: Wouldn't `EmailService` and `FakeEmailService` still be two separate classes even if you had no interface?

Comment: dependent classes should rely on abstractions and not concretions. this allows for greater flexibility as it allows you to replace production dependencies with fakes/mocks/stubs (choose your poison) when unit testing. it makes dependent code more SOLID.

Comment: Why can't your fake classes be subclasses of the real ones, with all the methods redefined?

Answer (score 1):

in java/jvm you have at least the following options:

1. add interface. as you mentioned, it adds a lot of noise
2. mock class. that's the most common, cheap and probably most useful option, if you don't like the syntax, you may create your own factory
3. inherit class. of course only if `EmailService` is not final. but it's not a good solution because it's easy to accidentally pass code execution into the original class (via constructors and not overridden methods) and have unexpected behavior in tests
4. use any other jvm language that allows duck-typing. e.g. groovy is very popular and easy to combine with java. it offers easy mocking. with spock framework you'll get more powerful mocking. but, imho, it has much worse refactoring support than java.
5. i'm not aware of any tools that does that but i can imagine, what you need can be achieved using some advanced code processing (like lombok) and/or custom class loading (like powermock). i can imagine using them to let you simulate duck-typing in java. but again, i haven't heard of any tool like that